# Module not recognized with sys.path in colab

Tags: python, module, google-colaboratory, clip, sys.path

I'm running on Google Colab with files mounted on Google drive.
I have set an absolute path that includes the file `CLIP`.

To call the subfile `clip` within, I use:

```
os.chdir(abs_root_path)
sys.path.append('./CLIP')
import clip
```

However, I get: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'clip'`
even though I can locate and see `clip` within `CLIP` in my drive: `/content/drive/MyDrive/.../CLIP/clip`

Comment: I am having the same issue.  Have you solved this?

Comment: I believe the answer worked unless I changed the path instead of absolute.

Comment: Why would you need to upload the files if they are already there?  They are just not being found by python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem once. I solved it by uploading files directly into google colab.

```
from google.colab import files

uploaded = files.upload()
```

Then you can browse your file and upload it.